# Error in Watson Visual Recognition service: Cannot execute learning task

Tags: ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I am repeatedly getting the error:"Error in Watson Visual Recognition service: Cannot execute learning task. : this plan instance can have only 2 custom classifier(s), and 2 already exist." It will not allow me to train my model. Can anyone help? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not see 2 custom classifiers when you list yours (GET /classifiers endpoint) then there may be a problem with your account, which would require filing an IBM Cloud technical support ticket to resolve at https://cloud.ibm.com/unifiedsupport/cases/add once you're logged in.